# How to display a blank page once a user logs into a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a html page that looks like the image provided and here is the source code. How can I display a blank page once a user logs in with 'admin' as both the username and password?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar">
        <h1>Login Here</h1>
        <form>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
            <a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
            <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to show a blank page once the user successfully logs in?

Comment: I actually was just using that as an example. I really just want the page to be redirected to a graph that uses similar code like this from jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: You are using ajax form submission or normal form?

Comment: Normal form. But it really doesn't matter because the data from the graph will still be outputted the same way.

Comment: The whole purpose of this login form is to redirect to my graph.

Comment: You have to add action attribut to the form `<form action="/action_page.php">`

Comment: If I want to redirect this to a html script named index.html that contains the entire code necessary to display the graph, how do I use the action attribute to do just that?